# How to enable cURL

Tags: php, xampp

I am installing Magento on xampp local server on Windows 7.After location, time ,currency setting then show PHP extension “curl” must be loaded.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

edit your php.ini file locate the "extensions" section and uncomment the php_curl.dll line.

more info at:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Answer (score 0):

Browse for the following files:

```
C:\Program Files\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini
C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
```

Remove the semicolon from this line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Then restart the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Edit

`;extension=php_curl.dll`

to:

`extension=php_curl.dll`

in your xampp php.ini files.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

in `xampp\php\php.ini`, and then restart the Apache service.

**To check it if actually works:**

Simply create a new php file with:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Load it in your browser and if you see `cURL support - enabled`, you're good to go.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Hope this helps.